# Xcode/Stackview, empty labels freaks out in stack view?

Tags: ios, xcode8, uistackview

hopefully an easy one here. I have some labels and text fields. Between them, I want some empty labels, which will if needed to be error texts. But when I try to stack view it all, Xcode zooms out and nothing can be seen on the viewController.
Anything else I need to change for it to work?

You can see a picture of it here before I hit stack view:

[image: Xcode]

The email label and text field are already in stack view, so are passwords, gentag passwords and label/button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This certainly appears to be a bug.  I duplicated your issue. I was able to solve it by setting a height/width to each empty spacer label, prior to adding it to my stack view.  This doesn't make sense because when you add an object to a stack view it loses all of the constraints it has.  None the less it resolved the issue:

[image]

Comment: The stackview needs to be email label and email text field. i dont know if this changes anything?

Comment: I just tested.  It doesn't matter how you configure your stack view.  As long as you set a height and width constraint of the empty label before you add it to the stack view, it works.  It behaves as it should.

Comment: I just tried, I add contraints to the empty label. But it still does the same. Anything I do wrong? Im using Xcode 8.3.3 if that does anything?

Comment: Jonas.  Please remove each stack view you have.  Click on the S.V.  Then on the Menu Bar select Editor -> UnEmbed.  This will remove the S.V.  Then add a height/width constraint to each empty label.  Then add everything back to your stack view(s) as you like.

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its just an auto layout issue (or lack of). Can be really messy, best to just keep playing around.

As you've already done, I would first put each label and its text field in a horizontal stack view and add constraints.

Then I'd add each of these stackviews to their individual warning labels in a vertical stackview and add constraints.

Finally I would combine all of the stackviews into one vertical stackview!

Comment: Just tried it, did just as before. As soon as I change the label text to nothing it does the same. Anything specific I should change?

Comment: Glad you found the solution! (And sorry, I assumed you'd already got constraints on the empty text fields.)

Comment: No Problem, im new to xCode and swift :)